# background image is not working in mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, css

The body background is not displaying in firefox.

here is my CSS

```
body{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    color: #fff;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background: url(../images/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: @Sowymya have you given the exact path  to you images folder ? please check tha....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when I have ran into this problem, the error comes from the path to the image. If I were you I would try changing that from your relative path  url('../images/yourimage.jpg') to the absolute path:
ex. url('home/user/Desktop/website/images/yourimage.jpg').

If you're site is linked to the folder containing images though(which it should), you won't need to do that. All you need is url('image/yourimage.jpg'); Because your site is already pulling the files from that folder

Comment: the quotes are irrelevant. I just use them for organization. Where your path is pointing is the important part

Answer (score 4):

I have had this problem in the past.....Your background images would not work in Firefox and Internet Explorer unless you set the display property to 'block' in your media queries.

For Example:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:740px) {
  table.Class {
    background:url('images/divider_small.png') no-repeat 10px 0; 
    width:430px;
    height:22px; 
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue problem was with the file path, I had "url('/images/yourimage.jpg')" which got loaded in chrome but not in ie and firefox so I changed to url('../images/yourimage.jpg') and it worked

Answer (score -1):

I notice that you have no '' around the URL to your image. On W3C schools it says you should:

For example:

```
background-image:url('yourImage.png');
```

Please see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image

Comment: W3Schools != W3C schools. It's an unofficial third-party site.

Comment: And, of course, given that it is W3Schools, it is wrong. The quotes are optional.

Comment: Yup @BoltClock is right its optional think before posting answers